# What is the most efficient way to update a key inside of an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have a JavaScript array including 10 objects with the following syntax:

```
const myArray = [{Age: 10, Name: Justin}, {Age: 15, Name: Bob}, ..., {Age: 20, Name: Jon}];
```

What's the most efficient way to update the Name key to be DisplayName. This is my currently logic:

```
myArray = myArray.map(item=>{return {age:item.age, displayName:item.name }});
```

Comment: `Array` is a built-in global. Do **not** name your variable, `Array`. Call it `myArray` or be more descriptive like `let people = [ ... ]`

Comment: You can use simple for, for in and for each loops. The best is for each for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is fine but can be shortened.

```
myArray = myArray.map(({ age, name }) => ({ age, displayName: name }));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by **shallow copy** and use **spread operator** to rename key of object

```js
const arr = [{Age: 10, Name: 'Justin'}, {Age: 15, Name: 'Bob'}, {Age: 20, Name: 'Jon'}];

function renameKey(obj, oldName, newName) {
  const { [oldName]: val, ...rest } = obj
  return {
    ...rest,
    [newName]: obj[oldName]
  }
}

const res = arr.map(i => {
  const tmp = renameKey(i, 'Name', 'displayName')
  return tmp
})

console.log('result ~> ', res)
```

or with `lodash`

```js
const arr = [{Age: 10, Name: 'Justin'}, {Age: 15, Name: 'Bob'}, {Age: 20, Name: 'Jon'}];
const res = _.map(arr, function(i) {
  return _.mapKeys(i, function(val, key) {
    return key === 'Name' ? 'displayName' : key
  })
})

console.log('res ~> ', res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the original Array, **never** use `map`. Because `map` is used to create a new Array from an existing one.

Instead loop through the nodes in Array. Create tehe new node with key `displayName` and delete the key `Name`.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const myArray = [{Age: 10, Name: 'Justin'}, {Age: 15, Name: 'Bob'}, {Age: 20, Name: 'Jon'}];
myArray.forEach((node) => {
  node.displayName = node.Name;
  delete node.Name;
});
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Why the never in bold?

Comment: @ksav because the objective of the user is to update the existing array. So he should **not** make use of `map` for that. Its purpose id to create new array and not update existing.